# How to Pretty Print XML returned from Requests lib in python

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, python-requests, pretty-print

I am using "requests" library to run SOAP services.

```
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
response = requests.post(test_url,data=testData.request_body,headers=headers)
```

the response comes as below (unformatted)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="https://xxx.abc.in"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:LoginResponse><return><SessionID>abc12345</SessionID><ResponseCode>0</ResponseCode><ResponseMessage>Successful</ResponseMessage></return></ns1:LoginResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

How do i pretty print this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use beautifulsoup passing `"xml"` as the parser:

```
x = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="https://xxx.abc.in"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:LoginResponse><return><SessionID>abc12345</SessionID><ResponseCode>0</ResponseCode><ResponseMessage>Successful</ResponseMessage></return></ns1:LoginResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>'''

print(BeautifulSoup(x, "xml").prettify())
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="https://xxx.abc.in">
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ns1:LoginResponse>
   <return>
    <SessionID>
     abc12345
    </SessionID>
    <ResponseCode>
     0
    </ResponseCode>
    <ResponseMessage>
     Successful
    </ResponseMessage>
   </return>
  </ns1:LoginResponse>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're starting from the xml string:

```
#LXML
from lxml import etree
xmlRootNode = etree.fromstring(resp_str)
xmlstr = etree.tostring(xmlRootNode, xml_declaration=True, encoding="UTF-8", pretty_print=True)
```

or

```
#xml
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import xml.dom.minidom
s = ET.tostring(xmlRootNode, encoding="UTF-8", method="xml")
xmln = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(resp_str)
xmlstr = xmln.toprettyxml()
```